# Trusted Sites in Captured Wim (Server 08 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mdt, wim

I have an inherited Windows Server 08 R2 .wim image used in MDT 2013. This image appears to contain custom Trusted Sites that are included after deployment, and stay there with every sysprep/capture when the image is updated.

The background to this is that I'm looking for a way (preferably without GPO) to add system-level Trusted Sites to Server 08 R2.

After multiple attempts with registry attempts and other non-GPO workarounds, I noticed that our Server wim already has a list of custom Trusted Sites included, as I stated before they are there after MDT deployment and remain there after a sysprep and redeployment. How can this be?

Based on my understanding of sysprep, WIMs and the per-user nature of Trusted Sites, I don't understand how these sites are in there. Even stranger, I tried adding my own Trusted Sites to the list through the IE Options menu and after sysprepping and redeploying the sites **I added** weren't there but the other ones are.

I mounted the wim and mounted all the registry hives available and searched for one of the custom domains in the Trusted Sites list and could not find anything.

Any ideas on how the old engineer could have done this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how this was done. The previous engineer loaded the C:\Users\Default\ntuser.dat into the registry and added the trusted sites into the Registry location.

The ntuser.dat in C:\Users\Default is basically the template that is loaded into HKCU for every Windows user that logs on and gets a profile created.